# Get r-length tuple combinations of m lists, with no more than a single element from any list, and r < m

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

In the example below, I have `m = 3` lists which and I calculate the combinations of size `r = 2`.

```
import itertools

a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
c = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']

print(list(itertools.combinations(itertools.chain(a, b, c), 2)))
```

**Output:**

```
[('a1', 'a2'), ('a1', 'a3'), ('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('a1', 'b3'), ('a1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'c2'), ('a1', 'c3'), ('a2', 'a3'), ('a2', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b3'), ('a2', 'c1'), ('a2', 'c2'), ('a2', 'c3'), ('a3', 'b1'), ('a3', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3'), ('a3', 'c1'), ('a3', 'c2'), ('a3', 'c3'), ('b1', 'b2'), ('b1', 'b3'), ('b1', 'c1'), ('b1', 'c2'), ('b1', 'c3'), ('b2', 'b3'), ('b2', 'c1'), ('b2', 'c2'), ('b2', 'c3'), ('b3', 'c1'), ('b3', 'c2'), ('b3', 'c3'), ('c1', 'c2'), ('c1', 'c3'), ('c2', 'c3')]
```

**Problem:**

I don't want the combinations that come from the same list. For example, `('a1', 'a2')` and `('a1', 'a3')` are should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Filtering the output of `itertools.combinations`

This is not necessarily the most elegant or performant solution, but it works.

```
def is_unique(comb, lookup):
    xs = [lookup[x] for x in comb]
    return len(xs) == len(set(xs))


def combine(args, r):
    lookup = {x: i for i, xs in enumerate(args) for x in xs}
    return (
        comb
        for comb in itertools.combinations(itertools.chain(*args), r) 
        if is_unique(comb, lookup)
    )


>>> list(combine((a, b, c), 2))
[('a1', 'b1'), ('a1', 'b2'), ('a1', 'b3'),      # (a1, b*)
 ('a1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'c2'), ('a1', 'c3'),      # (a1, c*)
 ('a2', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2'), ('a2', 'b3'),      # (a2, b*)
 ('a2', 'c1'), ('a2', 'c2'), ('a2', 'c3'),      # (a2, c*)
 ('a3', 'b1'), ('a3', 'b2'), ('a3', 'b3'),      # (a3, b*)
 ('a3', 'c1'), ('a3', 'c2'), ('a3', 'c3'),      # (a3, c*)
 ('b1', 'c1'), ('b1', 'c2'), ('b1', 'c3'),      # (b1, c*)
 ('b2', 'c1'), ('b2', 'c2'), ('b2', 'c3'),      # (b2, c*)
 ('b3', 'c1'), ('b3', 'c2'), ('b3', 'c3')]      # (b3, c*)
```

Comment: Ty for all Mateen, perfect answer :) !

Answer (score 2):

To slightly paraphrase the answer by Mateen, you could first choose `r` sets in `m choose r` ways in the outer loop, then iterate over the product of `r` sets in the inner loop. The order of the output may be different from other approaches.

```
lsts = [a, b, c]
def f(lsts, r):
  """
  lsts :: [[a]]
  r :: Integer
  Generate r-tuples with at most one element coming from
  each member of lsts.
  """
  m = len(lsts)
  assert m >= r
  for xs in itertools.combinations(lsts, r):
    for x in itertools.product(*xs):
      yield x
```

Comment: You could get a tuple of lists directly from `itertools.combinations`, if you just pass it `lsts` instead of `range(m)`. Then do `itertools.product(*tup)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is much neater.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a go-around solution but you may want to modify the list you get as output to keep only the desired values.

```
[i for i in a if i[0][0]!=i[1][0]]
```

With `a` being your list `a = list(itertools.combinations(itertools.chain(a,b,c), 2))`

Comment: Ty for your answer Zanga